# How to show selected menu item in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have menu in my application which is loaded using AngularJS and when I click on menu item I need to highlight this item. My menu looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked" data-ng-controller="ProjectListController" >
  <li data-ng-repeat="project in projects" data-active-link="{{project.id}}">
    <a href="#/project/{{project.id}}">{{project.title}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I create directive where I passing project id and inside of this directive I need to verify if

```
 $location.path() == '/project/project.id'
```

The problem there is when I came to my angular directive I don't have value for project.id, the value is assigned later, so I have 'project/project.id' as a text string which is not qual to $location.path()

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Change href="#/project/{{project.id}}" to ng-href="#/project/{{project.id}}"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have defined route in the format `/project/:projectId` in routeProvider. What you can do in your ProjectListController would be to assign the current projectid to a scope variable

`$scope.projectId=$routeParams.projectId;`

You need to inject the `$routeParams` service into your controller

Then in your html you can do

```
 <a href="#/project/{{project.id}}" ng-class="{selected:projectId===project.id}">{{project.title}}</a>
```

This applies `selected` class on the anchor with matches the route project id.

You can do the same in directive, by passing `$routeParams` service.